# Orchard CMS: Taxonomy Link Menu Visibility & Placement Issue

Tags: orchardcms, taxonomy

I just installed the [Forums module](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.NGM.Forum) to my Orchard site. Also, I created `Taxonomy Link` menu that serves as categories for the Forum posts.

By adding the Taxonomy menu to the `default layer`, I could make it appear on all pages. My questions are:

1. How can I make the Taxonomy menu (*i.e.,* Forums categories) appear only on the **Forums** page? It would have been simple if the Forums "page" was actually a page in Orchard context as I can just assign a custom layer to the page to control the visibility of the menu. But to my understanding, Forums is just a content type, which is not the same as a page -- in other words, I didn't create a Forums page; I simply created a new Forum with a permanent link to `"~/Forums"`.
2. I initially assigned the aforementioned Taxonomy menu to the `AsideFirst` zone but it would not show up for some reason. But it shows up just fine if I assign it to the (for instance) `ContentAside` zone. Is this a known bug?

Any non-programming solutions and/or workarounds (if any) will be most helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a url rule in a new "forums" layer, then put the widget in that layer.

2.Does the AsideFirst zone actually exist in your layer?

Comment: Bert - great to have you around in SO! I viewed several of your tutorials on Orchard, all of which were very helpful. :) 

Anyway, issue #1 is taken care of now - thanks for the tip. 

#2 is still puzzling me - I realized that `AsideFirst` zone may not be available for my theme. So, fine, I put my taxonomy menu in the `ContentAside` zone which I used for the default layer. But when I linked my menu in my custom Forums layer to the `ContentAside` zone, the menu would not display; I only see some empty space that supposedly belong to `ContentAside` but menu still doesn't render.

Comment: Bert - I decided to close this as #2 is more or less resolved now. I just went back to the default theme to use a different zone. My guess is this might have something to do with CSS issue.